# loop through files in the directory and copy over to another directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a bunch of files in one directory. I want to copy over(cut over) to another directory. But I want a few second delays between each files copying.

```
EG: C:/NewFolder has

test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

I need to move them to  C:/ResultFoler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET source=C:\NewFolder
SET target=C:\ResultFoler
IF NOT EXIST %target% MD %target%
FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.txt) DO (
    MOVE "%%f" "%target%\%%~nxf"
    PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
)
```

You can decide how long you want your bat to wait between two files by changing `-n 5` to the desired value.

Comment: how to do if i have a space in one of directory.

Comment: EG: directory like this: C:\temp\Spaces dir\

Comment: If you have spaces add " " around the path.